# How to assign a number to a floating point register using sparc assembly?

Tags: floating-point, sparc

For example, I want to assign 0x5 to %f1.  How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

The solution is save 0x05 in .data section, then load it to %f1.